# Как исправить ошибку отключения бота, если сообщение удалено?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Есть код. бот отвечает не всегда прямо моментально. Если удалить саму команду !привет или ответ бота Привет, то бот просто отключается и пишет ошибку. Как это можно исправить?

```
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
   if (message.author.bot) {
      return;
   }
    if (message.content === "!привет") {
      message.reply("Привет").then(() => {
         message.delete();
         message.guild.channels.cache.get('109138634428113548765').send("Поприветствуйте").then(msg => {
            setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 2 * 60 * 1000)
         });
      })
   }
});
```